# Graphs embedded in 3-manifolds

Tags: graph-theory, manifolds, geometric-topology

Is there any work done in graph theory, where graphs are embedded in different 3-manifolds? E.g. several graph properties can have expanded meanings in this case, even cycles can be of two types: trivial (bound a disk) or non-trivial...
What would be some references?

Answer (score 1):

Some keywords: "spatial graphs", "flat vertex graphs", "ribbon graphs"

An example is graphs show up as the 1-skeleton of a cellular/simplicial decomposition of a manifold.

There are invariants of embeddings of graphs, at least in $S^3$:

- *Yamada, Shûji*, [**An invariant of spatial graphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/jgt.3190130503), J. Graph Theory 13, No. 5, 537-551 (1989). [ZBL0682.57003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0682.57003).
- *Jaeger, François*, On some graph invariants related to the Kauffman polynomial, Boileau, Michel (ed.) et al., Progress in knot theory and related topics. Paris: Hermann. Trav. Cours. 56, 69-82 (1997). [ZBL0926.57002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0926.57002).
- *Murakami, Jun*, [**The Yamada polynomial of spacial graphs and knit algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02096726), Commun. Math. Phys. 155, No.3, 511-522 (1993). [ZBL0820.57007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0820.57007).
- *Reshetikhin, N.; Turaev, V.G.*, [**Invariants of 3-manifolds via link polynomials and quantum groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01239527), Invent. Math. 103, No.3, 547-597 (1991). [ZBL0725.57007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0725.57007). *(More references at [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Reshetikhin-Turaev+construction).)*

(Yamada doesn't mention this, but the polynomial is a renormalization of the $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}(2))$ Reshetikhin-Turaev invariant colored by the 3-d irreducible representation.)

In Dror Bar-Natan's answer for [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79488/is-there-a-knot-theory-for-graphs), he says that the theory of knotted graphs in $S^3$ reduces to the theory of tangles by choosing a maximal spanning tree and isotoping it to some standard form.